# Win7 locked (user prompt) w/ broken internet gateway : plug in android usb hotspot : will internet networking come up?

Tags: windows-7, networking, usb, android, login

A simple but unique question:

A) Windows 7 PC is logged on, but locked. eg: waiting at windows 7 user prompt for password.

B) Gateway which PC is connected to via WiFi is broken. eg: LAN works, but WAN access does not.

C) Will having my friend plug in my android based internet hotspot via USB while the PC is in a logged on but locked state bring up the gateway the android device will provide? Drivers for the USB PAN (?) device are already on the PC. I have used an android based hotspot via USB on this PC before. Also assume that all settings on the android are correct and the USB hotspot should work assuming the receiving end can accept it.

I am currently away from home and broke the settings on my router (openwrt based). I would like to have a friend who has keys come by and plug in his hotspot device so I can bring back my networking. The PC is question has openvpn running on it, and as long as windows provides it, it should bring up the vpn connection allowing me to fix my router.

Thanks!

Comment: Is LAN on computer working and connected to?